# Jupyter notebooks and git

Tags: jupyter

I am looking for any straightforward solution to work with Jupyter Notebooks and git since the cached data on the .ipynb files makes the diff difficult to read.

Does anyone know any standalone alternative and not server hosted?

Comment: The best way to do say is to just make a copy of that concerned .ipynb and rename it beginning with `tmp`

Comment: See `nbdime` (NoteBook DIff/MErge tools).  It integrates well with jupyterlab or jupyter, or command line.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to strip the output from the .ipynb file. Then the git diff would only track the cell data. One package that strips the output Jupyter Notebook is [nbstripout](https://github.com/kynan/nbstripout).

Comment: Won't the cell numbers be troublesome?